# want to get products group by category in mysql from multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables - Product, category and product_category.

```
|------ product-------- |
|-Pid
|-Pname
```

[image: Product table data]

```
|------ catrgory ----|
|-cat_id
|-cat_name
```

[image: category table data]

```
 |------ product_category --------------|
    |-product_id
    |-category_id
```

[image: product_table data]

Here is my attempts.

```
$comp_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT p.Pname AS product_name, p.Pid AS product_id,
       c.cat_name AS category_name, c.cat_id AS category_id
FROM product AS p 
JOIN product_category AS pc ON p.Pid = pc.product_id
JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = pc.category_id
Order BY category_id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($comp_query)){

        echo " $row[category_name] -----";
        echo " $row[product_name]<br/> ";

}
```

this query shows me result as :

```
Category1 ----- Category1-Product 1
Category1 ----- Category1-Product 2
Category1 ----- Category1-Product 3
Category2 ----- Category2-Product-1
Category2 ----- Category2-Product-2
```

BUt I want to get product from each category like:

```
**|-----Category1-----|**
|-Product-1
|-Product-2
|-Product-3

**|-----Category2-----|**
|-Product-1
|-Product-2
|-Product-3

**|-----Category3-----|**
|-Product-1
|-Product-2
|-Product-3
```

with product name and other details also.

Please help how can I do this with looping and query.

Comment: If a product can only have one category, it would be a lot easier to just have two tables: `Product (Pid, Pname, Pcategory)` and `Category (cat_id, cat_name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use 2 queries:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catrgory ORDER BY cat_name");
while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)) {
  print "**|-----".$cat['cat_name']."-----|**<br>";
  $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Pid IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_category WHERE category_id = ".$cat['cat_id'].") ORDER BY Pname");
  while($prod = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2)) {
     print " |***".$prod['Pname']."<br>";
  }
}
```

--> Update -->

I gave the 2 queries solutions because i thought you wanted to show empty categories...

in that case, just use your query above and replace your "while" loop with this:

```
$title_shown ='';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($comp_query)){
  if($row['category_name'] != $title_shown) {
      $title_shown = $row['category_name'];
      print "\n**|-----".$row['category_name']."-----|**\n";
  }
  print "|-".$row['product_name']."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this query also shows that category which has no product

Comment: this is not an optimized solution it will run queries for each category which will increase load on server instead i suggest you to use one joined query ordered with category and loop through results and for repeating category use if checks to category only once

Comment: acctually i want to do that and i tried may times. but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, your query looks good. You just need to group all products with the same category id at the php level. Just use a map with key=category_id, and value = {arrays of products}.
And populate this map right inside your while loop. Fragment in PSEUDO code just to get the main idea:

```
    while(...) {
        if (map.containsKey(category_id) {
             map.get(category_id).add(product);
        } else {
             Array products = new Array();
             products.add(product);
             map.put(category_id, products)
        }
    }
```